# System.Diagnostics.Trace or System.Diagnostics.WriteLine and CRM 2011 Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I don't know if I'm missing something or what, but all usages System.Diagnostics.Trace method in the CRM plugin execution doesn't work at all.

I have changed registry entry "TraceEnabled" according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699694(v=crm.5).aspx#BKMKserver_level_tracing and I believe I did everything to get it done but still nothing.

what I need is to have my Trace entries put into the file that I can found in the [CRM Installation]\Trace catalog.

Comment: The trace information is only display if there is an exception. Is your plugin executing as expected?

Comment: no but it didn't throw an exception. I solved the problem with the plugin and it was environment config problem but still - I would like to have some kind of logging system for future purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly - you will only see tracing details if an exception is thrown.

> During execution and only when that plug-in passes an exception back
>   to the platform at run-time, tracing information is displayed to the
>   user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx

Comment: so if I want some logging to files, I need all users that executes plugins actions to have the file system write access? (I can't set one user context for all execution). And then I'd need to implement this functionality by myself ?

Comment: Correct. Unless you can use the CRM OOB audit log and another plugin for that function.